# Create files in multiple folders

Tags: c#

I've created a `for` loop that creates *n* folders. I would like to create a text file in each folder. How do i do it?

```
for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++)
{                       
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(
        String.Format(@"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xx\Test{0:d2}", i));
}
```

I found a better solution.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++)
        {

            Directory.CreateDirectory(String.Format(@"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xx\Test"+i, i));                

            if (!File.Exists(string.Format(@"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xx\Test{0}/Test.txt", i)))
            {                    
                File.WriteAllText(string.Format(@"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xx\Test{0}/Test.txt", i), " ");
            }
```

Comment: I have updated code try latest one

Comment: Does this mean that you googled how to create a text file and found nothing???

Comment: I found how to create a text file but not in each folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++)
{                       
    var folder = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String.Format(@"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xx\Test{0:d2}", i));
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(folder.FullName + @"\WriteText.txt", "your text content");
}
```

**Update**

if you want more than one file

```
 for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++)
 {                       
    var folder = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String.Format(@"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xx\Test{0:d2}", i));
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(folder.FullName + @"\WriteText1.txt", "your text content 1");
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(folder.FullName + @"\WriteText2.txt", "your text content 2");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Do you mind explaining what does the "text" at the end do? Also, if I would like to create more than one text file in the folder, should I add another line of the writealltext or are there easier method?

Comment: it is the text content you write into the text file during file creation

Comment: yes you should use another line to create another text file

Comment: instead of adding another line, i found a better way to simplify the code. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var desktop_path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++)
{
    var folder_path = System.IO.Path.Combine(desktop_path, String.Format(@"xx\Test{0:d2}", i));
    var file_path = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder_path, "file.txt");
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folder_path);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(file_path, "content");
}
```

This code finds the current user's desktop path, and then uses `System.IO.Path.Combine` to ensure that paths are correctly concatenated together.

Comment: What's with the down-votes on this? What have I done wrong?

Answer (score -1):

```
  for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++)
    {                       
      var dir = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory
      (String.Format(@"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xx\Test{0:d2}", i));
      System.IO.File.Create(dir.FullName+ @"\MyFile.txt");
    }
```

To create add content on the file, we can use **FileStream** object returned by **File.Create()**

Answer (score -3):

Try this above,

I hope this may easy for you

```
 string path = @"d:\\dummyfolder";
        for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
        {
            string _folderPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", path, i);                
            if (!Directory.Exists(_folderPath))
            {
                //creating folder
                Directory.CreateDirectory(_folderPath);

                //creating text file
                string _filePath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}\\{1}.txt", path, i);                    
                string text = i + " " + "Content of the text file ";
                File.WriteAllText(_filePath, text);

            }
        }
```

Comment: why its down vote ? what wrong with this answer ? if answer is wrong i can accept with down vote. Without knowing anything to coming to vote, what a bull shut is there.... @stackover flow should consider about this